# Scala's parametric fields and constructor arguments

Tags: scala

I understand that *parametric fields* (like `x` in the example below) behave like normal fields; so you can reference them in methods:

```
class Test(val x: Int) { // x is a parametric field
  override def toString = "Test: " + x;
}
```

However, if you drop the keyword `val`, the code still compiles (and looking and the `.class` output, `x` is still a member of the class). So I am wondering, what is the difference between parametric fields (i.e., `val x: Int` in the above) and constructor arguments (`x: Int`)?

(With Java in the back of my head, I would have expected the scope of a constructor like `x` to *not* include a method like `toString`.)

Comment: I believe `x` still becomes a member if it is referenced in at least 1 method, regardless of whether or not it is prefixed with `val`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Without the `val` keyword, your code is similar to: `class Test (private[this] val x: Int) { ... }`. Therefore, `x`is available in the whole class but not from the outside.

It's not mentioned in your question but it might also be useful: in a `case class` the default modifier is `val`. Thus `case class Test(x: Int) {...}`is equivalent to `case class (val x: Int) {...}`.

Comment: Equivalent minus all the other stuff a `case class` has, of course. :-)

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral Actually, I hasn't precise it because the typo you corrected wasn't really a typo. ;)

Answer (score 4):

A constructor parameter effectively becomes a `private[this]` field but only if is referenced in at least one method.   Otherwise a field is not generated in the class.

For example:

```
class Foo(i: Int) {
  println(i)
}
```

becomes

```
$ javap -private Foo
Compiled from "Foo.scala"
public class Foo extends java.lang.Object implements scala.ScalaObject{
    public Foo(int);
}
```

But

```
class Bar(i: Int) {
  def baz = println(i)
}
```

becomes

```
$ javap -private Bar
Compiled from "Bar.scala"
public class Bar extends java.lang.Object implements scala.ScalaObject{
    private final int i;
    public void baz();
    public Bar(int);
}
```